# Prevent API method to be called more then once at a time

Tags: c#, api

I have an image upload function where i am able to drag and drop a lot of images at the same time to upload the images. This works fine but the problem is that the images when it is upploaded is supposed to get a specific id if it is the first one to get uploaded.

But as it is now i'm doing a check if there is any other uploaded and then if there isn't i upload the image. The problem here is that the first image hasn't been saved before the next one does the check if it is the first. So it will end up uploading all the images with the id that only the first should have.

Is there a possibility to make the repository method so that it only can get called one and have to save before the next call can reach the method?

EDIT:

```
    foreach (string fileName in request.Files)
            {
                var companyName = request.Form.Get(0);
                var productId = request.Form.Get(1);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyName))
                {
                    throw new Exception("No company found!");
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productId))
                {
                    throw new Exception("No product picked!");
                }
                HttpPostedFileBase file = request.Files[fileName];
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {



                    //This is the method that calls the API
                    SaveUploadResource(file, companyName, productId);
                }
            }
```

This is the repository method:

```
                var productImage = pamContext.ProductResources.Where(w => w.ProductId == productId && w.CompanyName == companyName && w.LanguageCode == "en" && w.ResourceTypeId == "I");
                if (!productImage.Any())
                {
                    productResource.ResourceTypeId = "I";
                }
                pamContext.ProductResources.Add(productResource);
                pamContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Are all parallel calls out of the same application?

Comment: yes it's a foreach loop that goes through all the files that the user draged. in the loop it calls the api

Comment: One more question: What means "the first one"? Is it the first upload for the whole application's lifetime, or ist there an upload process which is called more often and each call has a "first" upload? If you post the place in code where you call the API function giving advice is easier...

Comment: for the whole applications lifetime. I made an edit! Hope it helps

Comment: Cannot answer at the moment. Please clearify: is the "repository method" the function `SaveUploadResource` of your first code block? Is the upload strictly "one by one" or could the second picture be faster than the first and must be saved as the first then?

Comment: no, saveuploadresource is on the client side. It calls my api which have the repository method. I'm not sure what you mean by one-by-one but i guess it could end up in any order in the repository if the first call is slow. But that is not a problem. Which ever call that reaches the repository is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [Lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

```
    private Object myLock= new Object();

    foreach (string fileName in request.Files)
            {
                var companyName = request.Form.Get(0);
                var productId = request.Form.Get(1);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyName))
                {
                    throw new Exception("No company found!");
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productId))
                {
                    throw new Exception("No product picked!");
                }
                HttpPostedFileBase file = request.Files[fileName];
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    lock (myLock)
                    {
                        //This is the method that calls the API
                        SaveUploadResource(file, companyName, productId);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The lock will essentially pause any sequential executions until the preceding one has completed. Take care to ensure your method does not take too long to run relative to the number of calls being made, or response times could stack up and become very slow.

Comment: Awesome! That was exactly what i wanted! :) thanks!!